# Paypal error: Some required information is missing or incomplete

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have been successfully testing my site for a few weeks now and just when I was ready to go live with it, I suddenly get this error:

Some required information is missing or incomplete

With no explanation as to what is missing! I have not changed anything - this was working yesterday. I have tried clearing cookies, using a different browser, turning off my computer, resetting my IP and trying a different computer, but nothing works!

Our developer (in another conuntry) says that he can place orders just fine! I don't understand why he can but I cannot.

What would have caused this sudden error?  I use a custom cart on my site which sends this (as an example) to PayPal (and uses auto return to process things after payment is made):

```
<input type="hidden" value="Dress, Size 8" name="item_name_1">
<input type="hidden" value="345.00" name="amount_1">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity_1">
<input type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" name="cmd">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="upload">
<input type="hidden" value="0.00" name="tax_cart">
<input type="hidden" value="15.00" name="handling_cart">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="no_note">
<input type="hidden" value="JO" name="first_name">
<input type="hidden" value="BLOGGS" name="last_name">
<input type="hidden" value="Address" name="address1">
<input type="hidden" value="Address2" name="address2">
<input type="hidden" value="Town" name="city">
<input type="hidden" value="County" name="state">
<input type="hidden" value="AB1 2CD" name="zip">
<input type="hidden" value="email@gmail.com" name="email">
<input type="hidden" value="01245 123456" name="phone">
<input type="hidden" value="United Kingdom" name="country">
<input type="hidden" value="GBP" name="currency_code">
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="rm">
<input type="hidden" value="13|" name="custom">
<input type="hidden" value="http://www.mywebsite.com/payment-success.php" name="return">
<input type="hidden" value="email@mywebsite.com" name="business">
```

Comment: Would need to get a look at a full sample of what your site is outputting for the form to play with it and see if I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: On a side note, I would not recommend doing any post-payment processing on your return page.  Even with Auto-Return enabled there is no guarantee the user will actually make it back to that page, and you'll find that often times your code doesn't end up getting run so your automation doesn't work correctly.  Instead, use [Instant Payment Notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

Comment: It turned out that this was the culprit: _s-xclick  it needed to be _cart (and had been before - no idea how or when that got changed!)

Comment: Yes, I hear what you say about using autoreturn.  I have had the system developed for me by someone else. I was planning on putting a large red message on the checkout page reminding users to come back to the websiet after payment ot complete their orders.

Comment: Messages like that won't work, I promise you.  People won't see it or they simply won't read/comprehend it.  Their browser could crash or there could be any number of reasons they don't make it back.  I strongly encourage you to use IPN for post-payment processing.  Another advantage of IPN is that you can  handle things like e-checks correctly and automate the process of updating from Pending to Completed, and only fully process when truly completed.